# How do I iterate through each element in a list to append a \n at the end of each line inserted?

Tags: python

Here is my current code:

```
contentList = ["First line", "Second line", "Third line", "Fourth line", "Fifth line"]

for item in contentList:
    contentList.append("\n")

newFile = open("output2.txt", "w")
newFile.write(cleartext2 + "\n")
```

In the current code above,
I am attempting to go through each element to append a "\n" at the end of each line,
then writing a new file called output2.txt and inputting the contentList 's content

Currently, the content of listContent are being imported to output2.txt in one line separated by commas outputted like this:

```
[First line, Second line, Third line, Fourth line, Fifth line]
```

My desired output would be:

```
[First line
Second line
Third line
Fourth line
Fifth line]
```

Anything would help!

Comment: To do what you want, you need to loop over each element in the list.

Comment: @RandomDavis `listContent` is a list, not a string.

Comment: If `listContent` is just one big string, why not just do `listContent.replace(',', '\n')`?

Comment: You could also fix the way you create `listContent`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If it were a list, `listContent + "\n"` would not work.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice but `write()` can only accept a `str` or a `bytes` object, so `listContent` must be one of those. The fact that `listContent + "\n"` works must mean it's a `str`.

Comment: It's not a string, no new line character is added in any of the elements

Comment: When I open the text file, it's one string with all of the elements from listContents separated by comments

Comment: @bbsmfb we're just talking about the variable `listContent`, sorry for the confusion. Did you try `outfile2.write(listContent.replace(',', '\n'))` yet?

Comment: Wow, it worked!!!! Thank you Random Davis.

Comment: Thank you Code Apprentice and Random Davis for the collab and discussion!

Comment: To understand why your original version doesn't work, look closely at the for loop. It think `contextList.append('\n')` doesn't do what you think it does.